# How to do if I want blend two different colors using JButton?

Tags: java, jbutton

I have just started learning GUI in java yesterday.
And I want say sorry with my english because I'm not a native english speaker, but I hope everybody could understand my question. 
I did 3~4 examples about JFrame , JButton, JRadioButton, JComponent,  JToggleButton which were written in my book.

And! Now I'm doing my own example.  First, I thought to create a screen which shows that color which I want using JButton and JLabel.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.awt.*;

public class JButton_Color extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private JLabel screen = new JLabel("");
private JButton col1 = new JButton("Blue");
private JButton col2 = new JButton("Green");
private JButton col3 = new JButton("Pink");

public JButton_Color(){
setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
add(screen); add(col1); add(col2); add(col3);
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
screen.setOpaque(true);
col1.addActionListener(this);
col2.addActionListener(this);
col3.addActionListener(this);
setSize(100,200);
setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
Object action = e.getSource();

if(action == col1)
    screen.setBackground(Color.blue);

else if ( action == col2)
    screen.setBackground(Color.green);
else if ( action == col3)
    screen.setBackground(Color.pink);

 }  
 public static void main (String[] args){
 JButton_Color j_c = new JButton_Color();
 }
 }
```

It works perfectly, but it is not my final goal. I want to blend two colors which I clicked on. So, just for a test, I changed method actionPerformed little bit like that :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
Object action = e.getSource();
for (int i =0; i<2; i++){
if(action == col1)
    screen.setBackground(Color.blue);

else if ( action == col2)
    screen.setBackground(Color.green);
else if ( action == col3)
    screen.setBackground(Color.pink);
else if((action==col1)&&(action==col2))
    screen.setBackground(Color.yellow);

}
}
```

But that did not go well. How should I change my code? Actually, I have never learned about actionlistener and events.. but I want to achieve my goal!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: *"I have never learned about actionlistener and events.. but I want to achieve my goal!"* Would you drive a car without going to a driving school? take your tutorials tour first before making your on path: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Thank you for nice website and advice! But do you think is it for early? When I started reading GUI and some examples there were no examples which did not use Actionlisteners and events so I thought I could do that with simple algorithm tricks

Comment: *"But do you think is it for early?"* Yes. Before you can start painting you should learn how to mix colors. Without some background knowledge you will stumble through the dark instead of making progress.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Thank you for advices'! I will train more!( I have 500 pages to read more haha..)

Answer (score 0):

When the button is pressed, the `ActionListener.actionPerformed()` method is called, and `e.getSource()` is points to the button that was pressed. Your listener is invoked as expected, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the for loop.
If you want to blend the last two colors that were clicked on, you need to maintain the previous color in a variable, and when entering the actionperformed you can create the new color by creating a  new Color object as shown here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Blendtwocolors.htm. Then you set that as the color, and remember to update the previous color to what was just clicked!

Comment: Hmm.. Thank you for really nice answer!  The link and your texts are really helpful :)